# How to configure symfony2 to use custom translation file names convention?

Tags: php, symfony, translation

According to [official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#translation-resource-file-names-and-locations):

> The filename of the translation files is also important: each message file must be named according to the following path: domain.locale.loader:

I must to name all files such as `messages.en_US.php`, `navigation.en_US.php`, `admin.en_US.php` etc. and place in some folder.

```
i18n\
   admin.en.php
   messages.en.php
   navigation.en.php
   admin.fr.php
   messages.fr.php
   navigation.fr.php
```

But my project structure should follow the following structure:

```
i18n\
   en_US\
      admin.php
      messages.php
      navigation.php
   fr_FR\
      admin.php
      messages.php
      navigation.php
```

So how to configure symfony2 to support my structure and use translations in common way:

```
echo $this->get('translator')->trans('hello', array(), 'messages');
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, you have to load resources calling the `addResource()` method.

```
$translator->addLoader('php', new PhpFileLoader());
//Inside a loop:
$translator->addResource('php', 'path/to/messages.php', $locale);
```

Here is the documentation
https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/components/translation.html#loading-message-catalogs

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible. If you want to use Symfony, stick to the conventions from Symfony!

> To be correct: It's not possible in a simple way. You would need to write your own translator component and throw the translator component from Symfony away..

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you advise where should I reside this translator and what is the best place to execute it?

Comment: No, as Symfony is not thought to do so.